# ASP.NET error: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a Web project in VS 2010 (selecting ASP.NET project) and I wrote following code

```
<% page language="c#" %>

<html>

<head>
<title>Example 1: Hello World</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">

<h1>
<%
string strUsersBrowser = "";
strUsersBrowser+=Request.Browser.Browser;
strUsersBrowser+=Request.Browser.MajorVersion.ToString();
strUsersBrowser+="."
strUsersBrowser+=Request.Browser.MinorVersion.ToString();
response.write("<h1>Your web browser is " + strUsersBrowser + "</h1>")
%>
</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

VS2010 returns an error :

Error : A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Also, I saved that file as "**.aspx.cs**" extension

Where is the problem ?

// I SOLVED IT...

Comment: It should not be aspx.cs, just .aspx

Answer (score 1):

The declaration line

```
<% page language="c#" %>
```

does not specify a class or base-class.

Comment: +1 but there are too many issues -Response.Write  and he/she said "I saved that file as ".aspx.cs" extension".. :)

Comment: @Henk : could you be clear ? (some examples)...I am newbie in ASP.NET

Comment: @teodor Start with a normal template, ie __Project|Add New Item|Web Form__ . And you have a lot of spelling errors and missing `;`